# Set Value for HTML Radio Button from Array in Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

You will see in the APPS SCRIPT below that I am trying to assign a radio button value from an Array Value that I am calling as a variable (named data) in the above portion of the code you see below.  When I get a visual on the value of the button selected, though, it gives me the fixed value 'data[i][0]' instead of the actual value from the array.

```
function htmlOrders() {
  var active = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = active.getSheetByName("POHistory");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var myRange = sheet.getRange("A2:K" + lastRow); 
  var data = myRange.getDisplayValues();
  var optionsHTML = "";
  var seenType = {};
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     if(seenType[data[i][0]]) {
       continue;}
   seenType[data[i][0]] = true;
   optionsHTML += "<tr>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + "<input type=radio name=selectedPO value=data[i][0] onclick=radio();>" +"</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][0] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][2] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][1] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "<td>" + data[i][10] + "</td>";
   optionsHTML += "</tr>"
}
return optionsHTML;}
```

Comment: If I drop the quotes from "<input type=radio name=selectedPO value=data[i][0] onclick=radio();>", I get an error message stating this is an unterminated string.  At a loss for a fix here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot that html attributes must be wrapped in quotes as well. Also, wherever you have a continuous string, there's no need to put concatenation operator (+).

```
optionsHTML += "<td><input type='radio' name='selectedPO' value='" + data[i][0] + "' onclick='radio()';></td>";
```